# Remove Confirm navigation alert

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I am Doing a project in codeigniter. When  i am submitting my form browser shows an  alert "do you want leave this page". I need to remove this alert from all the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just add
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
inside your submit function
it will work..gud luck:)